# Where to specify roles in IsInRole()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I have a table called `users` with the basic user stuff.

Now I want to use roles but I have no clue where to specify this roles. Is this on a database level?

I want to use the method `User.IsinRole()` and I'm using `codefirst` design

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must specify your roles with seperate role table then associate with your user table of course. You can check Identity Framework, it came with asp.net mvc out of the box.

You can install identityframework with nuget from console like this;

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
```

I strongly recommend check this docs for basic usage information.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

For detail information you can check offical identity framework source code. It can be very useful for when you creating your own role system.

https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample/tree/master/AspnetIdentitySample

Answer (score 0):

[image]

These are the tables .NET generate for you if you want to have a basic RBAC in your application. I guess you have already generated these tables. You can then change your app.config or web.config accordingly to use by default methods to add roles and user to roles.

For detailed description have a look at this article

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb.aspx